# Loading the dictionary values in to the row values of a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a python dictionary

```
{1:cat,
  2:dog,
  3:sheep,
  4:foo,
  5:bar,
  6:fish,
  7:lion,
  8:shark,
  9:zebra,
  10:snake}
```

Also I have pandas dataframe as following 
`df`:

```
ID    col1    col2    col2   col4
18938   1       Nan     5      Nan
17839  Nan      2      Nan     8
72902   3       5       9      Nan
78298   7       Nan    Nan     6
```

Now I am trying to replace or map the values of each cell in each column the dictionary values and trying to `concat` all the column values to a new column.

The new `df` should look like:

```
ID    col1    col2    col2   col4     new_col
18938  cat      Nan    bar     Nan     cat|bar
17839  Nan      dog    Nan    shark    dog|shark
72902  sheep    bar   zebra    Nan    sheep|bar|zebra
78298  lion     Nan    Nan    fish     lion|fish
```

I am trying to achieve the 2nd step which is `concat` all the columns using the code

```
df['new_col'] = df.drop('ID',1).agg(lambda x: '|'.join(x.dropna().astype(str).values), axis=1)
```

but I am unable to get the first step working

I used

```
df = df.columns.map(dict)
```

but it is not giving me the expected answer I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
df = df.set_index('ID')
d1 = pd.concat([df[i].replace('Nan',pd.np.nan).dropna().astype(int).map(d) for i in df.columns], axis=1)
d1['new_col'] = d1.apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
print(d1)
```

Or if you want a little slower but more concise code:

```
d1 = df.apply(lambda x: x.replace('Nan',pd.np.nan).dropna().astype(int).map(d))
d1['new_col'] = d1.apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
d1
```

Output:

```
        col1 col2 col2.1   col4          new_col
ID                                              
17839    NaN  dog    NaN  shark        dog|shark
18938    cat  NaN    bar    NaN          cat|bar
72902  sheep  bar  zebra    NaN  sheep|bar|zebra
78298   lion  NaN    NaN   fish        lion|fish
```

Comment: You're dropping NaNs, how come your output still has NaNs?!

Comment: Because there are no values at the intersection of that row and column, we could replace that with '' or 0 or whatever  you like.

Comment: @pedrambashiri pandas like to keep the indexes aligned.  So, if there isn't a value for an index in a column, but the next column over has a value, then pandas will show that index and column cell with a NaN.

Comment: oh I see, so it's basically like 'Null' in databases, right?

Comment: Yes, NaN is the same as Null in databases. NaN stands for Not a Number.

Answer (score 2):

Use `df.replace()`:

```
df = df.replace(dict)
```

Note that if the keys in your dictionary are strings you may need `regex=True`:

```
df = df.replace(dict, regex=True)
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {1:"cat",
  2:"dog",
  3:"sheep",
  4:"foo",
  5:"bar",
  6:"fish",
  7:"lion",
  8:"shark",
  9:"zebra",
  10:"snake"}

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [123, 456], 'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [5, 6]})
df = df.replace(d)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    ID col1  col2
0  123  cat   bar
1  456  dog  fish
```